# possible appearance of algebraic curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I have a probably very easy question. I have some curve like the following given:

[graph of curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vaa6x.png)

Is there any argument to say just from the appearance of this curve, that it is not algebraic? And how I could determine its closure in the zariski topology.

Comment: No, all the more so as it *is* algebraic: it's defined by the polynomial equation $xy=1$.

Comment: Thanks. So in general it is not possible to conclude just from the "look" of a curve if it is algebraic or not?

Comment: In general, probably not, but algebraic curves are more nicely behaved.  For example, they can't oscillate too quickly.  Similarly, they intersect any line in a finite number of points.  So you can exclude some pathological cases.

Comment: An algebraic curve intersects a line in a finite number of points ($\leq$ its degree), so you have a negative test for non-algebraicity, that's all I can say.

Comment: It's missing the other part.

Comment: Okay. And regarding the second part of my question: Assuming that the curve turns out to be non-algebraic is there any way to conclude immediately that its zariski closure is the complete plane for example? (Also maybe just from the appearance of the curve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Zariski closure of any sort of planar curve is either a closed curve (possibly reducible) or the entire plane -- these are the only Zariski-closed sets there are, leaving aside isolated points.  So, unless your curve is "non-algebraic" because it's an algebraic curve with a bit of it erased, its closure is going to the the entire plane.

You cannot tell whether or not a well-behaved curve (like the one in your example) is algebraic by visually examining any bounded region of it, because the human eye is not going to be able to tell the difference between a function and, say, a ten-billion-term Taylor approximation of that function.