# Zariski closure of planar curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Why is the Zariski closure of any sort of planar curve either a closed curve (possibly reducible) or the entire plane (leaving aside isolated points)? Can someone give me a proof or an (online-)source for this.

(This question occurred as a consequence to my last question [link to last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085111/possible-appearance-of-algebraic-curves?noredirect=1#comment2209632_1085111) - since I could not find any proof for this nowhere)

Comment: Curve just means dimension 1.  The closure contains a curve so it's dimension at least 1 and it's contained in a plane so it's dimension at most 2.  That means the closure is either a curve or it's 2-dimensional.  So what are the 2-dimensional subvarieties of a plane?

Comment: "leaving aside isolated points" < this cannot happen!

Comment: I think there's some confusion here (at least on my end!) with terminology — you're using the word "curve" to mean at least two different things.

Comment: Thanks. Your right. I am also indeed still a bit confused with terminology. To be sure: What is here actually meant with "isolated"? "Isolated" needs also a topology in the background. Is here also the Zariski topology meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Zariski closure of a set (such as a planar curve) is the common vanishing locus of the ideal of functions that vanish on the set. So consider the ideal of functions that vanish on your plane curve. If this ideal contains only $0$ (the function that is $0$ everywhere), then the vanishing locus of this ideal is the entire plane. Otherwise the ideal contains some other function $f$, and the vanishing locus $V(f)$ would contain your planar curve.

Incidentally, the term "closed curve" that you use has a couple different meanings. Here it just means closed in the Zariski topology. Something like $xy=1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a (Zariski) closed curve in this sense, because it is the vanishing locus of a polynomial $xy-1$.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my question already. I thought "closed" is meant here in a geometric sense like [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClosedCurve.html)